# Deferred log file close

Tags: go, logging

My code works in that it compiles, and when executed writes out a log file using a buffered writer.

But I wonder whether:

1. I am correct in assuming that this *actually* winds up deferring a `.Close` that is always called
2. a package variable is the idiomatic way of doing this in Go

I realise that I *could* just have `createLogger` return the file pointer, and defer on that ... but that seems even weirder, to have `createLogger` set a package variable on log, then return the file pointer to be treated as a local ...

I'm still struggling with an idiom here.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "log"
    "os"
)

var logFile *os.File

func main() {
    createLogger()
    defer logFile.Close()

    // do some stuff
}

func createLogger() {
    logFile, err := os.OpenFile("log/app.log", os.O_RDWR|os.O_CREATE|os.O_APPEND, 0666)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("error opening file: %v", err)
        os.Exit(-1)
    }
    log.SetOutput(bufio.NewWriter(logFile))
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, on both counts (although putting it in the main package is not).

Typically I would return a `logFile` from `createLogger` (calling it `newLogger` is idiomatic), and defer closing the result.

If you're building a logger to work across your whole app, I'd look at how [the standard library does it](https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse/src/pkg/log/log.go?name=release#58).

Essentially, create a new package `my_app_logger` with an initializer which sets up the logger. That way, every package that includes `my_app_logger` gets the same logger instance.

Comment: Thanks - yes, that all makes sense.  I'm actually teaching myself Go as I ... go ... by writing a CLI app.  Everything started out in main() and then as I add functionality I'm refactoring.